# How to make a standard class part of project

Tags: .net, import, using

Is it possible to import the code in a dotNET class into the basic code of my project?

I know the normal is to add 'using ....' or include the class as part of the name when calling the class.

I also know that duplicating the code of the class in my project will make it bigger but it will also reduce the dotNET requirements of the target computer.

My project is a single file, non-install application.

Can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the class you are attempting to '`import`' is a standard framework class, then using the standard method of '`using`' will not cause any additional requirements on the target PC.

Comment: If I build my project on dotNET 4.5 because of the components requirements the client PC must also have v4.5 on to run and that I do not want. I want to build on v3.0 but use a function only available in v4.5

Comment: In that case you have no other option rather than completely duplicate code from framework 4.5 types you want to use and all of their dependent types. Almost impossible task, I suppose.